# Table in Android what am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-tablelayout, dynamic-tables

I don't get any error, but its not showing anything in the simulator. I want a dynamic table...

Content of the xml file:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1"
                android:id="@+id/maintable" >

        </TableLayout>
```

Code in the activity to add the tablerows and textviews:

```
 TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

                // Go through each item in the array
                for (int current = 0; current < strAuftraege.length; current++)
                {
                    // Create a TableRow and give it an ID
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                   // tr.setId(100+current);
                    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   

                    // Create a TextView to house the name of the province
                    TextView labelTV = new TextView(this);
                  //  labelTV.setId(200+current);
                    labelTV.setText(strAuftraege[current][0]);
                   // labelTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    labelTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tr.addView(labelTV);

                    // Create a TextView to house the value of the after-tax income
                    TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
                    valueTV.setId(current);
                    valueTV.setText(strAuftraege[current][1]);
                    System.out.println(valueTV.getText().toString());


                   // valueTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tr.addView(valueTV);

                    // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
                    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to use [TableRow.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html) when adding the TextViews to the table row?  You are currently using plain old LayoutParams.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
tr.addview(tv1,new TableRow.LayoutParam(
      android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParam.FILLPARENT,
      android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParam.WILLPARENT)
```

in place of

```
tr.addview(tv1,new LayoutParam(
      Layoutparam.FILLPARENT,
      LayoutParam.WRAPPARENT);
```

It will resolve your problem.